# Boton que elimine un cuadro de texto y un value de un div

Tags: php, javascript

Como dice mi pregunta, tengo un dilema en esta parte, y es que quiero yo crear un boton que con la accion de un javascript elimine un cuadro de texto y a su vez, reste un value de un div.

Tengo un script creado, pero cuando elimina el cuadro de texto, no elimina lo del div, tengo que hacer doble click para que elimine un valor del div.

Por ejemplo, mi div agrega tres cuadros de textos, y el valor del div aumenta a 3, pero al momento de eliminar un cuadro de texto, este desaparece pero el valor del div no, hasta el segundo click.

```
function quitarpaq() {
    var nump = document.getElementById('valnumpaq'); //Este es el ID del div con el valor

    if(div2.style.display == 'block') { //escogemos el div a eliminar
        div2.style.display = 'none'; // Si el div estaba activo, entonces lo eliminamos
        FillContenedor(<?php echo $lnLimite; ?>); //eliminamos el contenido del cuadro de texto
        nump.value= "<?php echo $lnLimite -1; ?>"; //Restamos uno al valor del div
<?php
for ($lnBulto = $lnLimite - 1; $lnBulto >= 1; $lnBulto--) { //Loop para eliminar varios cuadros de texto
?>
    } else if (div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display == 'block') {
        div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display = 'none';
        FillContenedor(<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>);
        nump.value="<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>";
<?php
}
?>
    }
}
```

Si podrian ayudarme con algun fiddle, estaria muy agradecido.

EDIT:

Coloco parte del codigo PHP con la cual tengo inconvenientes.

```
    <form class="form-envio" action="" method="POST" name="form1" id="myform1992" target="_self">
        <fieldset>
            <div class="divide"> </div>
            <h2>Peso y medidas</h2>
            <h3><img src="images/exclamation-mark.svg" width="18" height="18"/> No declarar el tamaño o peso correcto de tu paquete puede ocasionar cargos adicionales.</h3><br/>
            <div id="contenedor1">
                <div class="field-small">
                    <label>Peso (Kg) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtpeso1" name="txtpeso1" value="" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-small">
                    <label>Largo (cm) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtlargo1" name="txtlargo1" value="" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-small">
                    <label>Ancho (cm) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtancho1" name="txtancho1" value="" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-small last">
                    <label>Alto (cm) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtalto1" name="txtalto1" value="" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
    for ($lnBulto = 2; $lnBulto <= $lnLimite; $lnBulto++) {
    ?>
            <div id="contenedor<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" style="display:none">
                <div class="field-small">
                    <label>Peso<?php echo $lnBulto;?> (Kg) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtpeso<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" name="txtpeso<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" value="0" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-small">
                    <label>Largo<?php echo $lnBulto;?> (cm) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtlargo<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" name="txtlargo<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" value="0" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-small">
                    <label>Ancho<?php echo $lnBulto;?> (cm) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtancho<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" name="txtancho<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" value="0" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
                <div class="field-small last">
                    <label>Alto<?php echo $lnBulto;?> (cm) *</label>
                    <input type="text" class="small" id="txtalto<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" name="txtalto<?php echo $lnBulto;?>" value="0" required="" onkeypress="return soloEntero(event)" onkeyup="BLDefecto()" />
                </div>
            </div>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
            <div id="bultos" class="field-left">
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:agregarpaq()" id="agregarpaquete" name="agregarpaquete" >Agregar Bultos</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:quitarpaq()" id="quitarpaquete" name="quitarpaquete" >Quitar Bultos</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="javascript:clonarpaq()" id="clonarpaquete" name="clonarpaquete" title="Copia el Bulto 1" >Copiar Bulto</button>
            </div>


            <input type="hidden" value="1" name="valnumpaq" id="valnumpaq" />


    </form>
<script>
function agregarpaq() {
    var nump = document.getElementById('valnumpaq');

    if(div2.style.display == 'none') {
        div2.style.display = 'block';
        nump.value="2";
<?php
for ($lnBulto = 3; $lnBulto <= $lnLimite; $lnBulto++) {
?>
    } else if (div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display == 'none') {
        div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display = 'block';
        nump.value="<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>";
<?php
}
?>
    }
}

function quitarpaq() { //AQUI ME CAUSA PROBLEMAS
    var nump = document.getElementById('valnumpaq');

    if(div<?php echo $lnLimite; ?>.style.display=='block') {
        div<?php echo $lnLimite; ?>.style.display='none';
        FillContenedor(<?php echo $lnLimite; ?>);
        nump.value = "<?php echo $lnLimite -1; ?>";
<?php
for ($lnBulto = $lnLimite-1; $lnBulto >= 0; $lnBulto--) {
?>
    } else if (div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display=='block') {
        div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display='none';
        FillContenedor(<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>);
        nump.value="<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>";
<?php
}
?>
    console.log(document.form1.txtpeso3.value);
    }
}
function clonarpaq(clonar) {
    clonar  = typeof clonar !== 'undefined' ?  clonar : "S";
    var nump = document.getElementById('valnumpaq');
    if(clonar == 'S') {
        peso  = document.form1.txtpeso1.value ;
        ancho = document.form1.txtancho1.value;
        largo = document.form1.txtlargo1.value;
        alto  = document.form1.txtalto1.value;
    } else {
        peso  = "0";
        ancho = "0";
        largo = "0";
        alto  = "0";
    }

    if(div2.style.display == 'none') {
        div2.style.display = 'block';
        nump.value="2";
        FillContenedor(2, peso, ancho, largo, alto );
<?php
for ($lnBulto = 3; $lnBulto <= $lnLimite; $lnBulto++) {
?>
    } else if (div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display == 'none') {
        div<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>.style.display = 'block';
        nump.value="<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>";
        FillContenedor(<?php echo $lnBulto; ?>, peso, ancho, largo, alto );
<?php
}
?>
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Deberias agregar tu HTML.

Comment: sin el html esta complicado, debes agregarlo para ver, en js esta el removeChild y en jquery el remove, en realidad uso jquery para casi todo es más practico

Comment: Lo otro que no entiendo es porque usas php para eliminar varios si este no esta activo en la vista si es un código de servidor

Comment: ve esta muestra con jquery: http://jsfiddle.net/xfxstudios/h5z31tuy/6/

Comment: He añadido la parte del form que me esta causando inconvenientes.